# Are there any good examples of a pull to refresh feature for ListViews?

Tags: java, android, listview, twitter, datasource

The Twitter application for Android has a nice way of refreshing the listview by pulling down and automatically refreshing the data source.

Are there any good examples of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an Android Library project to provide pull to refresh:

https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh

Comment: Johannilson's implementation in my opinion had some issues with empty listviews and if the listview didn't have enough elements to cover the screen. A much better implementation is at https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh. It used in friendcaster app and I am using the same in my application

Comment: @gaurav You are correct. I actually already use the chrisbanes library in my own apps so I've updated the answer because this new library works much better and is still updated. Thanks for the reminder.